# Insert SumIfs formula into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a SumIfs formula into a cell with defined and locked ranges. The code itself,

```
Dim wb_stg As Workbook
Dim ws_stg As Worksheet
Dim ws_fwd As Worksheet

Dim ws_stg_daterng As Range
Dim ws_stg_stgrng As Range

Dim ws_fwd_sumrng As Range
Dim ws_fwd_daterng As Range
Dim ws_fwd_stgrng As Range

Dim fwd_stg As String
Dim fwd_date As String

' Locked references 
fwd_date = "'Fwd Planning'!J$3" ' Locked row
fwd_stg = "'Fwd Planning'!$A4" ' Locked column

Set wb_stg = ThisWorkbook
Set ws_stg = wb_stg.Sheets("Fwd Planning")
Set ws_fwd = wb_stg.Sheets("FwdPlan_Access")

ws_stg.Activate
' Reference ranges
Set ws_stg_stgrng = ws_stg.Range("A4:A30") ' Row references
Set ws_stg_daterng = ws_stg.Range("J3:AG3") ' Column references

' Data table
ws_fwd.Activate
Set ws_fwd_sumrng = ws_fwd.Range("E:E") ' Sum column
Set ws_fwd_stgrng = ws_fwd.Range("C:C") ' Storage name column
Set ws_fwd_daterng = ws_fwd.Range("D:D") ' Date name column
ws_stg.Activate

' Inserting the SumIfs formula into the wanted cell
ws_stg.Range("J4").Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & ws_fwd_sumrng & "," & ws_fwd_stgrng & ", " = " &" & fwd_date & "," & ws_fwd_daterng & ", " = "" & fwd_date & ")"
```

Then the error that is given,

[image]

Ultimately I am trying to insert this formula in this cell J4 and then PasteSpecial it into the rest of the wanted range. If there is a simpler well, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: think it may be that `=` you have there

Comment: `ws_stg.Range("J4").Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & ws_fwd_sumrng.Address() & "," & ws_fwd_stgrng.Address() & ", " = " &" & fwd_date & "," & ws_fwd_daterng.Address() & ", " = "" & fwd_date & ")"`  You cannot pass a range into a string.  You need to pass the address which is a string to a string.

Comment: And you can just do the full range at once: `ws_stg.Range("J4:AG30").Formula = ...`

Comment: Thank you, @ScottCraner, this still gives a type mismatch error. Using, ```ws_stg.Range("J4:AG30").Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & ws_fwd_sumrng.Address() & "," & ws_fwd_stgrng.Address() & ", " = " &" & fwd_stg & "," & ws_fwd_daterng.Address() & ", " = "" & fwd_date & ")"```

Comment: @ScottCraner, these two address ranges are on a different tab, if that matters.

Comment: you also have some `"` missing: `ws_stg.Range("J4").Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & ws_fwd_sumrng.Address() & "," & ws_fwd_stgrng.Address() & ", " & fwd_date & ", " & ws_fwd_daterng.Address() & ", " & fwd_date & ")"`  The `=` are implied and not needed.

Comment: Ah, the other sheet.  You will then need to use `.Address(0,0,xlA1,1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner, you're a godsend. Ultimately what worked, ```ws_stg.Range("J4:AG30").Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & ws_fwd_sumrng.Address(0, 1, xlA1, 1) & "," & ws_fwd_stgrng.Address(0, 1, xlA1, 1) & ", " & fwd_stg & ", " & ws_fwd_daterng.Address(0, 1, xlA1, 1) & ", " & fwd_date & ")"```